# Limits of integration on probability problem

Tags: probability

Let $f_{x,y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{x}$ where $0<y<x<1$

Show that this is a valid pdf.

I know I need to do the double integral and have it equal 1 but I can't get it to work.

I tried $\int_0^x\int_y^1\frac{1}{u}dudv$ since x goes from y to 1 and y goes from 0 to x but I can't get to $=1$ just stuff with log in it

I tried $\int_0^x\int_y^1\frac{1}{x}dxdy$ for the same reason as above except without using dummy variables.

I realize this shouldn't work since the order of integration doesn't matter (right?) but I also tried $\int_y^1\int_0^x\frac{1}{x}dydx$ and got a different answer from because the $\int_y^1\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\,dy\,dx$ gives me $\int_y^1\frac{1}{x}x\,dx$ which is then just $1-y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the region for which your function is not zero is a triangle bounded by $ y=0$, $y=x$, and $x=1.$

Therefore we have $$ \int_{R}f=$$

$$\int_0^1\int_{0}^x 1/x\,dy\, dx=$$

$$
\int_0^1 1/x
\int_{0}^x\,dy
dx=  $$

$$  \int_0^1 (1/x)
(x)
dx=  $$

$$                 \int_{0}^1dx=1.$$ and since your function $f(x,y) = 1/x $ is positive over the region, f(x,y) is a probability density function.

Comment: Could you help me understand why the X dimension isn't from y to 1?  It seems intuitive that the Y dimension is from 0 to x but it seems like the X dimension should be from y to 1 since X can't be lower than Y.  What am I missing?

Comment: According to the definition of  your region  $0<y<x<1$ , x goes from $0$ to $1$ but y goes from 0 to x.  To see the range of x, cover y. It is a little bit confusing but that is how we interpret the given inequality. The first integral always have fixed limits.

Answer (score 1):

You must integrate over the whole plane...yet you usually get a nicer integral:

$$\iint_{\Bbb R}f_{x,y}(x,y)dA=\int_0^1\int_y^1\frac1x\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1-\log y\,\mathrm dy=\left.(y-y\log y)\right|_0^1=1-0=1$$

Observe the last one is an *improper convergent integral* ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $R$ be the support of the density. Note that
$$
\int_{R}f=\int_0^1\int_{0}^x 1/x\,dy\, dx=
\int_0^1 1/x\left[
\int_{0}^x\,dy
\right]dx=\int_{0}^1dx=1. 
$$